# Pattern Not Matching in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match a pattern in VBA but it doesnt work.I am Trying to match a pattern like -> 1:0

```
If Cells(i, 7) Like "[0-9]\:[0-9]" Then
Range("G" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Else
CountDTPSelectionError = 1
Range("G" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ErrorsLog = ErrorsLog & TimeStamp & " Error: " & "DTP Selection Is not Defined Correctly" & vbNewLine
End If
```

This code colours even the Correct matched Values.I want only the pattern that is does not match the above regex should be coloured red.

Comment: Try this `Like "#:#"`

Comment: Thanks it works fine.But what was the problem in my code any idea.When I paste the same regex in regex pattern website with 1:0 as input it shows correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to escape the colon to make it a literal colon. No need to do that in `VBA` and `Like` operator ***nor*** in the regex simulation you have used. `\:` simply tells the engine to use a literal colon, however just using `:` results the same effect, [it's allready literal](https://regex101.com/r/d6Ybv3/1). Furthermore it seems that you are checking ratio's? If so, then I think `0:1` would be an invalid ratio? Therefor see the following:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("12:9", "1:9", "1/9", "0:1)

For Each el In arr
    If el Like "[1-9]:#" Then
        Debug.Print el & "= Correct"
    Else
        Debug.Print el & "= Incorrect"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Where `#` is short for `[0-9]` within the operator. Keep in mind, though [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) and regular expressions share similarities, they are **not** the same!

**Note:** If `0:1` is a valid pattern then simply change to `#:#` as per @YasserKhalil mentioned in the comments.